# Can't log string in Robot Framework from method which placed in custom library

Tags: python, database, ssh, robotframework

I have Robot Framework test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    garda_db_library.py

*** Variables ***
#SSH
${SSH_ADDRESS}    
${SSH_USERNAME}    
${SSH_PASSWORD}    

#DB
${DB_NAME}    
${DB_USERNAME}    
${DB_PASSWORD}    

*** Test Cases ***

Example Test

    Connect Ssh    ${SSH_ADDRESS}    ${SSH_USERNAME}    ${SSH_PASSWORD}

    Connect Db    ${DB_USERNAME}    ${DB_PASSWORD}    ${DB_NAME}

    Execute Query    SHOW TABLES;

    ${query_results}    Get Query Results

    Log To Console    ${query_results}

    Close Connection
```

and have my custom library:

```
import pymysql
import sshtunnel


class GardaDatabaseLibrary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tunnel = None
        self.cnx = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect_ssh(self, ssh_address, ssh_username, ssh_password):
        self.tunnel = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ssh_address_or_host=ssh_address,
            ssh_username=ssh_username,
            ssh_password=ssh_password,
            remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306),
        )
        self.tunnel.start()

    def connect_db(self, db_username, db_password, db_name):
        self.cnx = pymysql.connect(
            user=db_username,
            password=db_password,
            host='127.0.0.1',
            database=db_name,
            port=self.tunnel.local_bind_port,
            client_flag=pymysql.constants.CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS
        )
        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()

    def execute_query(self, query):
        self.cursor.execute(query)

    def get_query_results(self):
        return str(self.cursor.fetchall())

    def close_connection(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnx.close()
        self.tunnel.stop()


library = GardaDatabaseLibrary()


def connect_ssh(ssh_address, ssh_username, ssh_password):
    library.connect_ssh(ssh_address, ssh_username, ssh_password)


def connect_db(db_username, db_password, db_name):
    library.connect_db(db_username, db_password, db_name)


def execute_query(query):
    library.execute_query(query)


def get_query_results():
    library.get_query_results()


def close_connection():
    library.close_connection()
```

When i trying to log query_results, test passed, but variable query_results is None. Why? I used my library in python program and it print good and long query_results.
Also i had this problem in another project with Get Json, and i can't log json string, because json string always none.

I tried google, using chat gpt, tried Log to Console and Log Many, but it doesnt help.

Comment: The first thing I see is that the function `get_query_results` does not return anything.